# Invalid API Key for Alchemy Service in Bluemix Console

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I have 2 issues:

- I added the AlchemyAPI to my services list in the Bluemix console, but when i goto the Manage Tab, nothing shows there (it just shows a page permanently moved error) so i cant launch the service.
- Also the api-key that is created for this workspace doesn't work. It complains about invalid-api-key (yes i know that this is a known issue, but none of the other questions seems to have a definite answer on how to fix, has anything changed that i should try???). I have tried both free and standard plans for both issues and waiting for like 2 days now still no luck.

Comment: I got the same results as you when trying to add the Alchemy services, so this may be a result of a bug. Your best bet is to open a Bluemix support ticket by clicking the Support tab on the upper right corner of your console. I'm adding ibm-watson-cognitive and alchemyapi to your post, to try to get the attention of someone more closely associated with that service.

Comment: Are you still having part 1 of this issue? I just viewed the manage tab for the AlchemyAPI service and it now displays an overview with links to documentation.